# Duplicating program

Tags: java

I can't understand what a lecturer of mine has given.

The task is:

1. Let us suppose that we get a number from the command line.
2. Duplicate that number.

The given code is:

```
public class Duplicate{
    public static void main(String[] args){
            r = r * 10 + ch - '0';
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(r*2);            
    }
}
```

Well, I can see that this works, but I can't understand how. Then I decided to show the results of every line of this code.

```
public class Duplicate{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args[0].length(); i++){
            System.out.println("Iteration " + i);
            System.out.println("Initial value of 'r' for this iteration = " + r);
            char ch = args[0].charAt(i);
            System.out.println("charAt(i) = " + args[0].charAt(i));
            System.out.println("r * 10 = " + Integer.toString(r * 10));
            System.out.println("r * 10 + ch = " + Integer.toString(r * 10 + ch));
            System.out.println("r * 10 + ch - '0' = " + Integer.toString(r * 10 + ch - '0'));
            r = r * 10 + ch - '0';
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(r*2);            
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Iteration 0
Initial value of 'r' for this iteration = 0
charAt(i) = 3
r * 10 = 0
r * 10 + ch = 51
r * 10 + ch - '0' = 3

Iteration 1
Initial value of 'r' for this iteration = 3
charAt(i) = 2
r * 10 = 30
r * 10 + ch = 80
r * 10 + ch - '0' = 32

64
```

Frankly speaking, I can't catch the mechanism. Could you clarify what is happening line by line?

Comment: The given code is invalid. What does "duplicating a number" means?

Comment: Why not just `System.out.print(args[0]); System.out.print(args[0]);`? Anyway, try casting your int(s) above to `(char)`.

Comment: @JB Nizet, pardon for that. The program should double what it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're converting a string representation of an integer to an integer.

For every iteration of the loop, you get the first "unconsumed" character. Then you "append" it to your resultant integer.

Let's break your formula down:

```
r = r * 10 + ch - '0'
```

To understand this better, I'd rewrite this as:

```
int currentCharacterValue = ch - '0';
r = r * 10 + currentCharacterValue;
```

Let's say you had the string "123". To begin with, r is initialized to 0.

First iteration of the loop:

```
ch = '1'
currentCharacterValue = '1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1 ('1' is 49 in ASCII and '0' is 48)
r = 0 * 10 + 1 = 1
```

Second iteration of the loop:

```
ch = '2'
currentCharacterValue = '2' - '0' = 50 - 48 = 2
r = 1 * 10 + 2 = 12
```

Third iteration of the loop:

```
ch = '3'
currentCharacterValue = '3' - '0' = 51 - 48 = 3
r = 12 * 10 + 3 = 123
```

So you end up with r = 123, which is in integer representation of the "123" string. Once that's done, you just multiply r by 2 to get your final result (because Java can only understand multiplication of numeric values, and not of strings). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you doing addition of integer with character value, addition will happen with the ascii value of the character. Thats why you get 51 when you add 'ch' variable with zero. Even 'r' is zero you get 51 bcoz thats the integer representation of the character you given at commandline

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this is to teach you to get an integer from a number of digits.

The algorithm works by doing what our positional system does, where

```
 132 = 1*100+3*10+2*1
     = ((1*10)+3)*10 + 2
```

You start out with 0, and with every digit, you multiply the number you have already by 10 and add the numeric value of the digit to get a new number. You do this until all digits are processed.

Now, the numeric value of a digit d is precisely (d - '0'). This is so because, happily, the code numbers for digits are arranged in consecutive order. Note that, if this were not so, we could still find out the numerial value with code like:

```
 switch (d) {
    case '0' : return 0;
    case '1' : return 1;
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The lines that are of great interest are:

```
char ch = args[0].charAt(i); //let's further refer it as line 1
```

and

```
r = r * 10 + ch - '0'; //let's further refer it as line 2
```

And let's assume the argument to your program is `32`.

In Java, all arguments to a command line program are passed to the `main` method as `String`s. So the `args` array will contain a single element - the string "32".

The `for` loop iterates through the characters (`char` variables) of this `String`. What you have to understand is that the numeric value of a `char` representing a digit is not equal to the value of that digit. Instead, it is the numeric value given by the ASCII code of that character.

I.e. `char`s from `0` to `9` will have numeric values ranging from 48 to 57.

Let's look at line 1 (as I labeled them above). There, you isolate the character corresponding to your iteration through the `String`.

The statement at line 2 can be broken down for a better understanding, as follows:

```
int digitVal = ch - '0';
r = r * 10 + digitVal;
```

The first line in the above snippet does the following: subtract the ASCII value of the character `0` from the actual digit character. E.g. if `ch` is `'2'`, then `digitVal` will store value `2`.

Then, at the next line the digit numeric value is used in an arithmetic expression for building the numeric value step by step. E.g. if we are at digit `2` from number `32`, that line will do: `r = 3 * 10 + 2`, which will store `32` as an `int` value in `r`.

After the iteration through the digits is done, the number parsed from the `String` (e.g. `32` as an integer parsed from `"32"` as a `String`) will be stored in variable `r`. What remains to be done is print `r` multiplied by 2, which happens in the last line of the `main` method.

So, what happens step by step with the input `32` is the following:

-- read the input as a `String`; that is `"32"`;
-- initialize `r = 0`; this will store the parsed number

-- find the first character: `'3'` as a 'char';
-- translate it to its corresponding numeric value (not the ASCII value!); that is `3`;
-- r = r *10 + 3 = 0 * 10 + 3 = 3;

-- find the second character: `'2'` as a 'char';
-- translate it to its corresponding numeric value (not the ASCII value!); that is `2`;
-- r = r *10 + 2 = 3 * 10 + 2 = 32;

-- print r * 2

Anyway, this should only work as a teaching example. All the below could have been done simpler in one line of code:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * 2);
```

This solution will also take care (i.e. throw an exception) of the case when the input is not a number, e.g. `"3a"` or `"Bazinga!"`.